# How to implement a sandboxed python interpreter in django to allow user to upload and run code with limited file-system access

Tags: django, sandbox, pypy, empythoned

I'm looking at building a web based learning environment for Python-based bioinformatics programming. I'm aiming for a mix of [***Codeacademy's***](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-OGNHh?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) interface, with [***Rosalind***](http://rosalind.info/problems/list-view/)-style questions, preferably implemented in Django.

I need to offer some limited file system access (for upload, download, and access by the interpreter), as bioinformatics problems often involve large biological datasets, while still ensuring server security.

As I currently understand, there are two possible ways of doing this:

- A client-side interpreter, such as [***empythoned***](https://github.com/replit/empythoned) (Used at [***repl.it***](http://www.replit.com/Fir/1) and, I believe, Codeacademy)
- A server-side sandboxed interpreter such as the [***PyPy sandbox***](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)

Would anyone have any one have any recommendations on the best way to go

Comment: You might want to take a look at [IPython's Notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html). The code-sections of the notebook are full-on Python environments. I don't know what the security considerations might be, but the implementation is hyper slick. Check out some of the [videos form PyCon 2012](http://ipython.org/presentation.html).